restart my script as if it were the first time
I want to see press a button to restart my script as if it were the first time. For this I am forced to close blender, open blender again, open the script, and finally launch the script. Isn't there a faster way?

i recommend using VSC with the add-on from Jacques. video explanation: https://youtu.be/q06-hER7Y1Q?si=mX1tC2C6EwX_gPyH
